# Javascript callback function - doubts and Misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I was checking online about callback functions and i read two articles which make me confused . I will not mention websites but one of this it's very popular , the scenario is this :

**Website 1:**

- Callback function :

  ```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").hide("slow", function(){
          alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
      });
  });
  ```
- Not Callback function :

  ```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").hide(1000);
      alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
  });
  ```

**Website 2 :**

- Callback function :

  ```
  $("#btn_1").click(function() {
    alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
  });
  ```

Checking the code above i would like to know why "not callback function" in website1 is different than "callback function" in website2 and i would like to know an explanation about which is a real call back function and which one is not,checking the examples above.

Comment: they're all have callback functions, website 1, bullet 1,has 2 callback functions, website 1, bullet 2 has 1 callback function, and website 2 also has 1 callback function

Comment: W3Schools (website 1) has its limits ...

Comment: A callback is a piece of executable code passed as argument to another code. In all 3 pieces of code there are callback functions, but I suppose the 1st website is only talking about the function to execute the alert inside of `.hide()`, in `$("p").hide("slow",function(){alert("The paragraph is now hidden");});`, which isn't in the other code, and the second website is talking about the function inside of the `.click()`, in `.click(function() {alert("Btn 1 Clicked");})`.

Comment: It's a misunderstanding caused by a poor definition of "callback function" by website 1. Not your fault. They should have explained that both had callback functions but one of them had 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**They all have callback functions.**

This has 2 callback functions (inside click, and inside hide):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
});
```

This has 1 callback function (inside click):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

This has 1 callback function (inside click):

```
$("#btn_1").click(function() {
  alert("Btn 1 Clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Callback function**:

> A function that is passed as an argument to another function and when
>   some task is done then this callback function will call.

**Website 1:**

***For Callback function*:**
*(Here just one thing callback within callback)*

Here we passed a function as an argument to another function so this is callback

***Not Callback function*:**

Here same thing as below, we don't care about what the body of the function
So this is also a callback function.

**Website2:**

Here we can see that we are passing a function as an argument. So callback function.